# ¿Cómo solucionar el error de Heroku? "No web processes running"

Tags: javascript, php, heroku

espero alguien pueda ayudarme, ya que me pasé semanas intentando solucionar el error de mi página web hecha en PHP, JavaScript, CSS3.
Adjunto una pantalla del error de mi página:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También adjunto los `logs` desde el CLI de Heroku:

```
introducir el código aqu
2023-01-14T03:03:20.762949+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web 
processes running" method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=armandobolanios.herokuapp.com 
request_id=8d54957c-f6ce-4e17-a2a4-a1fbca2c4588 fwd="95.108.213.219" dyno= connect= 
service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-01-14T03:34:42.163032+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web 
processes running" method=GET path="/" host=armandobolanios.herokuapp.com 
request_id=af914ab1-e9b8-4442-97ec-c68d5e32e2ea fwd="95.108.213.219" dyno= connect= 
service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-01-14T03:35:24.312617+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web 
processes running" method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=armandobolanios.herokuapp.com 
request_id=a0274b47-bac0-4f33-ae4d-01f41c1bc9f8 fwd="95.108.213.219" dyno= connect= 
service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-01-15T20:19:53.291436+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web 
processes running" method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=armandobolanios.herokuapp.com 
request_id=664524bb-b41e-417a-b5e5-21201537086a fwd="87.250.224.144" dyno= connect= 
service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-01-15T20:19:57.211780+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web 
processes running" method=GET path="/" host=armandobolanios.herokuapp.com 
request_id=c6faea74-9c3e-4938-b1fc-214788ecf7d6 fwd="87.250.224.184" dyno= connect= 
service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-01-15T20:20:01.277986+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web 
processes running" method=GET path="/" host=armandobolanios.herokuapp.com 
request_id=fdebe1ce-28f8-4605-bf73-be53e6afc728 fwd="87.250.224.70" dyno= connect= 
service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-01-15T20:20:04.902498+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web 
processes running" method=GET path="/" host=armandobolanios.herokuapp.com 
request_id=14f7f073-6d7c-4695-aaf1-abac9f4ee314 fwd="87.250.224.70" dyno= connect= 
service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-01-15T20:28:17.283665+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web 
processes running" method=GET path="/" host=armandobolanios.herokuapp.com 
request_id=d3a5ed3c-8f11-49f1-bd62-983abe7330be fwd="173.252.83.2" dyno= connect= 
service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2023-01-15T20:28:20.650611+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web 
processes running" method=GET path="/public/img/profile/profile.svg" 
host=armandobolanios.herokuapp.com request_id=e618986a-1615-40ad-b304-bf4f8019a7d4 
fwd="66.220.149.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2023-01-15T20:28:30.660419+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web 
processes running" method=GET path="/" host=armandobolanios.herokuapp.com 
request_id=9e869f50-e62a-474d-acaf-d46c7de61fd1 fwd="173.252.83.119" dyno= connect= 
service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2023-01-16T17:07:14.215675+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web 
processes running" method=GET path="/" host=armandobolanios.herokuapp.com 
request_id=617b054a-4649-473c-aa9f-1d9347b7ddf3 fwd="187.228.79.76" dyno= connect= 
service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-01-16T17:07:15.028370+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web 
processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=armandobolanios.herokuapp.com 
request_id=8d25c558-403d-4ac4-9c81-3886b1594fe6 fwd="187.228.79.76" dyno= connect= 
service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

La verdad, yo pensé que la plataforma de Heroku era gratuita para alojar mi sitio web como prueba, no sé si debo pagar un precio para que se aloje en ese servidor.

Comment: Tu lo has dicho. [Era gratuita](https://thenewstack.io/where-can-heroku-free-tier-users-go/#:~:text=Wise%20added%20that%20starting%20Oct,free%20dynos%20and%20data%20services.) [FAQ de Heroku](https://help.heroku.com/RSBRUH58/removal-of-heroku-free-product-plans-faq)

Comment: Lo que puso el de arriba, debes pagar por el servicio ahora